# Trigger Runs 12 times

Tags: apex, trigger, callout

I have code that hits a Lambda for integrations. The plan is once they have created an Account, Closed one Opp & Contacts it sends for the first time and the writes back with the SAP ids. Then if they make edits on the Contact OR Account it is supposed to send an upsert. For some reason though, when I try and make an opp that already has an existing Account SAP ID it will send the UpsertExistingContacts like 12 times. The plan is that it will only fire the UpsertNewOpprotunity once OR UpsertExistingContacts once. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

AccountTrigger:

```
trigger accountTrigger on Account (after update) {
for(Account acc : trigger.new)
{   
    if(acc.SAP_BP_Code__c != null && trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id).SAP_BP_Code__c != null)
    {
        //Run for new Updates for Accounts 
        UpsertExistingContacts.UpsertAccountandContacts(Id.valueOf(acc.id));
    }
}
}
```

ContactTrigger:

```
trigger contactTriggerHandler on Contact (after insert, after update) {
for(Contact con: trigger.new){
    string conAccID = Id.valueOf(con.AccountId);
    if(con.Account_SAP_ID__c != null && trigger.oldMap.get(con.id).SAP_Contact_ID__c == trigger.newMap.get(con.id).SAP_Contact_ID__c){
        
        UpsertExistingContacts.UpsertAccountandContacts(Id.valueOf(con.AccountId));
        break;
    }
}
}
```

OpportunityTrigger:

```
trigger UpsertNewOpporutnity on Opportunity (after update) {
for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new)
{
    
    if(opp.StageName == 'Closed Won' && trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName != 'Closed Won')
    {
        //Run for new Closed Deals
        UpsertNewOpportunity.UpsertNewOpportunity(Id.valueOf(opp.Id), Id.valueOf(opp.AccountId));
    }
}
}
```

UpsertNewOpportunity:

```
public with sharing class UpsertNewOpportunity{

@future (callout=true)
public static void UpsertNewOpportunity(String oppId, String accountId) {

    System.debug('Closed Won - ' + oppId);

    //account level fields missing - Email, OtherPhone

    Opportunity oppResult = [Select DocNum__c, DocEntry__c, Customer_PO__c, SAP_Quote_CardCode__c, WHSE_Instructions__c,Primary_Contact__r.SAP_Contact_ID__c, Sales_Employee_Code__c, Owner.User_Code__c, Owner.Owner_Code__c, Discount__c, Shipping_Type_Code__c, Shipping_Cost__c, Billing_Address__r.Name, Shipping_Address__r.Name, Terms_Code__c, (Select Product2Id, ProductCode, Description, Quantity, Discount, UnitPrice From OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oppId];
    List<Contact> contactsResult = [Select Primary__c, Name, FirstName, LastName, MailingAddress, Position__c, Title, SAP_Contact_ID__c, Email, Phone, OtherPhone, MobilePhone FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :accountId];
    List<Address__c> addressesResult = [Select SAP_S_Row_Num__c, SAP_B_Row_Num__c, Name, Address__c, Address_2__c, Address_3__c, Billing__c, Shipping__c, City__c, State__c, Zip_Code__c, Building_Floor_Room__c, Country__c, Ship_to_Name__c, Phone__c, Email_address__c FROM Address__c WHERE Account__c = :accountId];
    List<Lambda_Endpoint__mdt> awsEndpoint = [Select id, UAT__c, Production__c, ApiKey__c from Lambda_Endpoint__mdt Limit 1];
    Account accountResult = [Select Industry_Code__c, SAP_BP_Code__c, Name, Corp_Name__c, Website, Status__c, Phone, Price_List__c, Price_List_Id__c, Channel__c, Series__c, Owner.User_Code__c, Discount__c, Parent__c, Terms_Code__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];
    
    
    Map<String,Object> payload = new Map<String, Object>();
    payload.put('BusinessPartner', accountResult);
    payload.put('Addresses', addressesResult);
    payload.put('Contacts', contactsResult);
    payload.put('Quote', oppResult);

    String json = json.serialize(payload);
    
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

    if(Utls.runningInASandbox()){
        req.setEndpoint(String.valueOf(awsEndpoint[0].UAT__c));
    }else{
        req.setEndpoint(String.valueOf(awsEndpoint[0].Production__c));
    }
    

    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setHeader('ApiKey',awsEndpoint[0].ApiKey__c);
    req.setBody(json);

    HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
    system.debug('response'+ response);

    System.debug('response==='+response.getBody());

    // Parse the JSON response

    if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
        System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
    } else {
        System.debug(response.getBody());
    }
    System.debug(json);
}
}
```

UpsertExistingContacts:

```
public class UpsertExistingContacts {

@future (callout=true)
public static void UpsertAccountandContacts(String accountId) {

    //account level fields missing - Email, OtherPhone
    
    List<Contact> contactsResult = [Select Primary__c, 
                                           Name, 
                                           FirstName, 
                                           LastName, 
                                           MailingAddress, 
                                           Position__c, 
                                           Title, 
                                           SAP_Contact_ID__c, 
                                           Email, 
                                           Phone, 
                                           OtherPhone, 
                                           MobilePhone 
                                    FROM Contact 
                                    WHERE AccountId = :accountId];
    List<Address__c> addressesResult = [Select SAP_S_Row_Num__c, 
                                               SAP_B_Row_Num__c, 
                                               Name, 
                                               Address__c, 
                                               Address_2__c, 
                                               Address_3__c, 
                                               Billing__c, 
                                               Shipping__c, 
                                               City__c, 
                                               State__c, 
                                               Zip_Code__c, 
                                               Building_Floor_Room__c, 
                                               Country__c, 
                                               Ship_to_Name__c, 
                                               Phone__c, 
                                               Email_address__c 
                                        FROM Address__c 
                                        WHERE Account__c = :accountId];
    List<Lambda_Endpoint__mdt> awsEndpoint = [Select id, 
                                                     UAT__c, 
                                                     Production__c, 
                                                     ApiKey__c 
                                                FROM Lambda_Endpoint__mdt 
                                                Limit 1];
    Account accountResult = [Select Industry_Code__c, 
                                    SAP_BP_Code__c, 
                                    Name, 
                                    Corp_Name__c, 
                                    Website, 
                                    Status__c, 
                                    Phone, 
                                    Price_List__c, 
                                    Price_List_Id__c, 
                                    Channel__c, 
                                    Series__c,
                                    Owner.User_Code__c, 
                                    Discount__c, 
                                    Parent__c, 
                                    Terms_Code__c 
                            FROM Account 
                            WHERE Id = :accountId];
    
    Map<String,Object> payload = new Map<String, Object>();
    payload.put('BusinessPartner', accountResult);
    payload.put('Addresses', addressesResult);
    payload.put('Contacts', contactsResult);
    //payload.put('Quote', oppResult);

    String json = json.serialize(payload);
    
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

    if(Utls.runningInASandbox()){
        req.setEndpoint(String.valueOf(awsEndpoint[0].UAT__c));
    }else{
        req.setEndpoint(String.valueOf(awsEndpoint[0].Production__c));
    }
    
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setHeader('ApiKey',awsEndpoint[0].ApiKey__c);
    req.setBody(json);

    HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
    system.debug('response'+ response);

    System.debug('response==='+response.getBody());

    // Parse the JSON response

    if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
        System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
    } else {
        System.debug(response.getBody());
    }
    System.debug(json);
}
}
```

Comment: 1/2: At first blush, there doesn't appear to be anything "wrong" per se. Having `@future` calls inside of a loop is naturally going to limit how much data your triggers will be able to work on (the better approach would be to send the entire collection of Ids once to your @future method, which would then be responsible for filtering data and then making callouts). It also means you'll naturally call `UpsertAccountandContacts()` multiple times if your trigger is processing more than a single record (i.e. you do an update via Apex rather than through the web UI)

Comment: 2/2: The other thing you need to realize here is that a trigger can cause triggers on other objects to fire as well. Does your trigger on `Opportunity` update a `Contact`? If so, then you'll see the `Contact` trigger fire as well. Have a rollup field on `Account` that summarizes `Opportunity` records? Then a trigger on `Opportunity` will cause the `Account` trigger to run as well, even if you don't explicity perform DML on it. There is some chain of events causing the behavior you're seeing, and understanding that chain of events is something you're going to need to do yourself.

Comment: 3/2: (pesky off-by-one errors, man, I tell ya). You'll need to spend some quality time poring over the log file you get in your org. The "Analysis" view that you can get to in the Developer Console can help you get a broad idea of what's happening (i.e. trigger X is running, which causes trigger Y to run, which causes trigger Z to run, etc...)

Comment: BTW, I know Salesforce have recommended using a Future from a trigger to allow callout, but this is a broken pattern. Take a look at [this article on ApexHours](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/) for a robust solution that avoids use of async process limits and the constraints on the number of asyncs you can initiate in a synchronous or async context.